# Hi ,everyony I am beginner at calculus and I learn it on my own by using precalculus book openstax>

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

For the following exercise, graph
$$
y=x^2
$$on the given domain. Determine the corresponding range. Show each graph.

$[−10, 10]$ is not supposed to be the all real number?

Why when I found the answer in the answers section I found the answer is $[0,100]$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I lost you at "$[-10, 10]$ is not supposed to be the all real number?" Of course the interval $[-10,10]$ is not the set of all real numbers. But I don't think that's what you're trying to ask. Can you state the question more clearly?

Comment: I formated your question with MathJaX as far as I could. Feel free to adjust it to reflect what you wanted. But when doing so, please clarify and be very specific in what you are asking.

Comment: @littleO Given the answer, the only possible interpretation of the question was they wanted that as the restricted domain, I gave an answer for that

Answer (score 3):

They are asking you to look at the function $f(x)$ on the restricted domain of only values in $[-10,10]$.  On these numbers, the smallest the output gets is $0=0^2$ and the largest is $100=10^2=(-10)^2$, and as the function is continuous it hits everything in between, thus on the restricted domain, you get the range is $[0,100]$